# Regexp to cut all text inside the external quotation signs

Tags: regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

Please help me with adjusting regexp. I need to cut all text inside the external quotation signs.
I have text:

```
some text "have "some text" here "that should" be cut"
```

My regexp:

```
some text "(?<name>[^"]*)"
```

Need to get

```
have "some text" here "that should" be cut
```

But I've got

```
have
```

Comment: Is there any reason to check for balanced double quotes inside the outer most double quotes? I mean, if you just used the dot instead of negated `"` it [would also match your sample string](https://regex101.com/r/nTC4sM/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to supported the first level of nested double quotes you can use

```
some text "(?<name>[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rGE5xT/2).

*Details*:

- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than double quotes
- `(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `"[^"]*"` - a substring between double quotes that contains no other double quotes
  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than double quotes.

If your regex flavor supports recursion:

```
some text ("(?<name>(?:[^"]++|\g<1>)*)")
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rGE5xT/4). Here, `("(?<name>(?:[^"]++|\g<1>)*)")` is a capturing group #1 that matches

- `"` - a `"` char
- `(?<name>(?:[^"]++|\g<1>)*)` - Group "name": zero or more sequences of

  - `[^"]++` - one or more chars other than `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `\g<1>` - Group 1 pattern recursed
- `"` - a `"` char

Comment: I've just wonder why regexp returns <have should> if I enter <some text "have should" cut">   (odd number of "). I still need text inside external quotations -<have should" cut>

Comment: @IdurJul Because the double quotes are not paired. They must be paired.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to remove all text up to the first quotes then retain everything till the last quote, you can try this.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mXBR5l/1)

```
[[:alpha:]][^"]*\"(?<name>.*)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with nested regexp operators:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(Regexp_substr(regexp_replace(word,'(^")|("$)'),'["].+'),'(^")') as Result

from(

 SELECT  '"some text "have "some text" here "that should" be cut"' as word from dual)
```